# Lawvere - Conceptual Mathematics - Criterion for decomposition of a map into two pieces

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is a problem from Lawvere's Conceptual Mathematics in a section talking about when we can find solutions to 'choice'/lifting diagrams.

I have maps: $h\colon A \to C$, $g\colon B \to C$ with the property:

For all $a \in A$, there is a $b \in B$ such that $h(a) = g(b)$.

I want to show there exists a function $f$ such that $h = g \circ f$.

I would define $f(a) = b$ where $b$ is an element guaranteed by our mapping property. Potentially, there are multiple such elements $b$, in which case we would fix a $b_0 \in \{b | h(a) = g(b)\}$.

To show that $f$ is well defined we must show:

1. $f$ is defined for all elements on the domain.
2. $f$ only maps to elements in the codomain.
3. If $a$ and $a'$ are elements in $A$ such that $a = a'$ then $f(a) = f(a')$.

1) and 2) are true by definition of $f$ since every element $a$ is mapped to an $h(a)$ and we are only assigning $f(a)$ to values in $B$.

For 3), I think the argument goes like this:

Let $a, a' \in A$ be such that $a = a'$. Since h is a well defined function, $h(a) = h(a')$, and by our assumed property there exists at least one $b \in B$ such that $g(b) = h(a)$. If there is only one such $b$ then $g(b) = h(a) = h(a') \implies f(a) = f(a') = b$. If there is more than one such $b$, we have fixed $b_0$ in our definition of $f$ so $f(a) = f(a') = b_0$ where $b_0 \in \{b | h(a) = g(b)\}$.

Does my argument for 3) look OK? I always get a little confused trying to prove these well-definedness of functions...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick remark before addressing your proof. The "one-valuedness" property of functions is not $a=a^\prime\implies fa=fa^\prime$. This implication always holds since the equality $a=a^\prime$ *means* $a,a^\prime$ are completely interchangeable. "One-valuedness" means that $fa$ is a single element of the target/codomain.

I think your proof is fine, but there is an important subtlety. You are *choosing* for every $a\in A$ an element $b\in B$ satisfying $g(b)=h(a)$. Note that when $A$ is infinite, it is not "physically evident" that one can make an infinity of choices. The assertion this is possible is known as the *axiom of choice*. It plays an important role in many branches of math.

---

The following uses the notion of "fiber" (inverse image of a point). Forgive me if it is not familiar to you.

The following conditions are reformulations of each other.

- there exists $b\in B$ such that $gb=ha$.
- the fiber of $g$ over $ha\in C$ is non-empty $g^{-1}(ha)\neq \emptyset$.

Your proof suggests to *choose* an element from each fiber $g^{-1}(ha)$ for $a\in A$. A pleasant related formulation of the axiom of choice is the following: "every surjection (epimorphism of sets) has a section."